# get node by address field and part of name

Tags: 7, nodes, database

I have a content type which have a name field and address field.

I want to retrieve programmatically all the nodes in a specific city and wich contain in his name one or many keywords.

For example i want to search in "Paris" the node wich contain in name the word "beautiful" and/or "shop". Then i can retrieve theses results :
- "My beautiful shop of candies" in "Paris"
- "Fast shop" in "Paris"

The problem is that i don't know how to get nodes by a word containing in :/

Here is my current code :

```
$query  =  new EntityFieldQuery();

$entities  =  $query->entityCondition( 'entity_type', 'node' )
    ->propertyCondition( 'status', 1)
    ->fieldCondition( 'field_adress', 'locality', 'Paris', 'like' )
    ->fieldCondition( 'field_name', 'value', array('beautiful', 'shop', 'money') )
    ->execute();

dsm($entities);
```

I tried to change :

```
->fieldCondition( 'field_name', 'value', array('beautiful', 'shop', 'money') )
```

to

```
->fieldCondition( 'field_name', 'value', array('beautiful', 'shop', 'money'), 'CONTAINS' )
```

but I get this error :

> Warning : addcslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
>   dans DatabaseConnection->escapeLike() (ligne 984 dans
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/fritr/includes/database/database.inc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by building the query up in smaller chunks and using a loop to add the field conditions for the mulitple words .  I'm not sure how of how you'll be passing the data in but say you have an array of words in $words.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query-->entityCondition( 'entity_type', 'node' )
    ->propertyCondition( 'status', 1)
    ->fieldCondition( 'field_adresse', 'locality', 'Paris' );

foreach ($words as $word){
   $query->fieldCondition('name', 'value', $word, 'CONTAINS');
 }

$result = $query->execute();
```

This code isn't tested and I've written off the top of my head. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3AfieldCondition/7.x

Comment: Ahh it's an another approach i try it and tell you if it works